# TypeMismatchNamingException in spring boot with IBM MQ

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am trying to create a Spring boot project to read messages from a queue and do some processing.

I have defined the Jndi ConnectionFactory in application.properties

```
spring.jms.jndi-name=java:/MyConnectionFactory
```

On starting the application I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl] available at JNDI location [java:/MyConnectionFactory] is not assignable to [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]
```

I am deploying the code on a jboss server with the given jndi.

Not sure if in this scenario some different implementation is needed for the ConnectionFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Bean public DefaultMessageListenerContainer orderMessageListenerContainer() {
 DefaultMessageListenerContainer endpoint = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
 endpoint.setMessageListener(new YourMessageListener());
 endpoint.setDestination("yourDestination");
 endpoint.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
 return orderDefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory().createListenerContainer(endpoint);
}
```

Solved manually with DefaultMessageListenerContainer.

Comment: I tried to format your code some, but if you edit the answer you can just pasted in the original between the lines with just ``` on them, this will allow it to be spaced how you want it (fixed width font).